# Error in adding headers to http.get in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular4-httpclient

I'm trying the following code:

```
  let myHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    myHeader.append("Authorization", Token);
    return this.http
      .get(this.service.GetDomainPrefix() + "Source/Download/" + id, 
        {       
          headers: myHeader, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
    }).map(res => {
    return {
      filename: name + '.mp4',
      data: res.blob()
    };
  })
```

but getting the following error:

> Argument of type '{headers: HttpHeaders; responseType:
>   ResponseContentType.Blobl;}' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'RequestOptionsArgs'. Type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to type
>   'Headers'

The problems is only with the headers, because without it there are no errors.
How can I add a head to my get request?

Comment: Is this for adding a security token to every request? If so, wouldn't be better an interceptor to do that instead for adding the header in every place you have an http request?

Comment: Are you using http(@angular/http) or HttpClient(@angular/common/http) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you are using `HttpModule` (angular 2,4) instead of the new `HttpClientModule` (angular 4,5,6)
(and the `Http` class instead of `HttpClient` class)

Also, HttpHeaders are immutable. To use the new HttpClientModule, use this code

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
//...
let myHeader = new HttpHeaders().append("Authorization", Token);
    return this.http
      .get(this.service.GetDomainPrefix() + "Source/Download/" + id, 
        {       
          headers: myHeader, responseType: 'blob'
    })
.map(res =>  {
      filename: name + '.mp4',
      data: res
          })
```

And you need to modify your `AppModule` to import `HttpClientModule` instead of `HttpClient`

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working. Error: Argumet of type headers: httpheaders; responsetype; responsecontenttype; is not assignable to parameter of type {headers? httpheaders; observe?: body; params?: httpparams...............

Comment: Did you set `responseType: 'blob'` like in my answer?

Comment: `res` is already a blob with the new `HttpClient`. I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

// HttpClient(@angular/common/http)

```
let myHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    myHeader.append("Authorization", Token);
let options =  {       
          headers: myHeader, responseType: 'blob'
    }
```

// Http(@angular/http)

```
 let myHeader = new Headers();
    myHeader.append("Authorization", Token);

let options = new RequestOptions() {       
          headers: myHeader, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
    }
```

//Request

```
return this.http
      .get(this.service.GetDomainPrefix() + "Source/Download/" + id, options).map(res => {
    return {
      filename: name + '.mp4',
      data: res.blob()
    };
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

`import {Headers} from 'angular2/http';
var headers = new Headers();`

This is what you should use. It's written in the error in simple words i.e. not assignable to type HttpHeaders(). You must use Headers()